# How to get Ruby to work (on .gitbook)?

Tags: ruby, git

I'm trying to get Ruby to run so that I can draft a contribution to the Git Community Book.

I'm on windows XP. I've downloaded Ruby 1.9.2 and the dev kit. I've downloaded the gitbook and its files [.gitbook](https://github.com/schacon/gitbook)

I'm now at the situation where it tells me it can't find the script files, and after trying updating the windows Path variable, and moving the .gitbook folder to various locations I still can't make any progress..

The trace option gave the following (sorry it doesn't format properly!). It still looks like some silly path error but help is needed...

```
D:\Ruby192\bin\gitbook>rake html --trace
(in D:/Ruby192/bin/gitbook)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- script/merge
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
D:/Ruby192/bin/gitbook/Rakefile:1:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `block in load_rakefile'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `block in run'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
D:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `load'
D:/Ruby192/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Any advice welcome.

Comment: This look like it might be due to the change in how ruby 1.9 handles `require` - the current directory is no longer included in the path searched, and this code assumes it is. The last commit date on the gitbook repo is from a couple of years ago, so they might have been using ruby 1.8.7. You could try installing 1.8.7 instead of 1.9.2 and try that. (I'm not on windows so I don't know how easy or hard that would be unfortunately).

Comment: I'll try that. I only get chance in the evenings as that is when I get connectivity..

Comment: Tried Ruby 1.8.7, but still in some dependency hell. Looks like this will have to be abandoned (unfortunately).

Comment: @matt - I can't even get as far as Philip. Following the `README` I can't get past the `gem install ...`. I've now tried 1.9.2, 1.9.1, 1.8.7 and 1.8.6, using `rvm`; The later two fail to `gem install` both `discount` and `ultraviolet` while the earlier versions only fail on `ultraviolet`, so I too have failed to work out how to build gitbook. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rakefile in github is like,

```
require 'script/merge'
```

to make it work in ruby 1.9.x edit as follows

```
require './script/merge'
```

Comment: I'll have a try in the next few days. Many thanks for the suggestion.